# jQuery click() event on a tag

Tags: jquery

I wanna use jQuery to add a class to a tag after clicking it, and get a delay of 1 second before navigating to the target ?

Below is the tag:

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This....

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('newClassName').delay(1000);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('classname');
  setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
});
```

If you have target="_blank" then you would be able to see the effect of changed class otherwise if it is target="_blank" then you will have new page loaded.

Comment: I think what OP want to apply the class first then wait for 1 sec then proceed with the default action.. where the default action part may not work as expected

Comment: I think it will does as you stated, as I have setTimeout after apply class.

Comment: the problem is with the redirect, if the `a` has a `target="_blank"` then the possible redirect code will not work as expected

Comment: If other than target="_blank" or target="_blank" ?

Comment: Can you check it to by changing to 5000, from 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
$('a').click(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
         $(this).addClass('yourClass');
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("someclass");
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    },1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = this.href
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("classToAdd");
    alert("a tag assigned a class: "+ $(this).attr("class"));
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    },1000);
    return false;
});
```

### **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/6g2hQ/)**

Comment: undefined =>  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");

Comment: try it on your system and then report me back. Try alerting the same.

Comment: after alert go the different link and undefined URL => http://192.168.1.200/artpoint/undefined